# Send SESSION GET information in POST contact form together with the POST fields

Tags: php, forms, session, post, get

On the website i'm currently working on I made a list (cart idea) where customers can put products on. It works with GET method + a session, the code for the making of the session is as follows:

```
`<?php session_start(); 
require("dbconnect.php");
?>
<?php 
     if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
         $cart = array();
         $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
     }  

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add"){             
        $id=intval($_GET['id']); 
                if(in_array($id, $_SESSION['cart'])){
                    if (($key = array_search($id, $_SESSION['cart'] !== false))){
                        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
                    }
                }
                else {
        array_push($_SESSION['cart'],$id);      
                }

    } 

            if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="delete"){
            $id = intval($_GET['id']);
                    if (in_array($id, $_SESSION['cart'])){
                         $key = array_search($id, $_SESSION['cart']);
                        unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
                    }
        }  
?>
```

Nothing special, just a regular cart in a session with an array where I put all the unique product codes to remember what is on the list. Now when customers go to the page where they could send the list of product they also can select how many of each product they want. They have to fill in a number and when they are done they click on the button 'calculate (berekenen in my language)' and they get the subtotal price of all the products, the VAT and the total price. However, I want it this way that the customer can fill in their personal information plus the list plus the amounts to be send in an e-mail. I made selfmade PHP forms myself earlier but now i'm getting stuck. I use GET for the order list but I always use a POST form for my contactforms. How can I manage to make one button that sends the list plus the amounts plus the input of the contact form fields to me? At this moment I tried it as follows (and many more ways, but it all failed so far).

```
<main>
            <div class="main-center">
                    <div class="offerte-container">
                            <form action="" method="get" value="offertelijst">
                            <ul class="offerte-list">
                                    <?php
                                      $per_page = 9;
                                        $args = array(
                                        'post_type'=> 'wpcproduct',
                                        'order'     => 'ASC',
                                        'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
                                        'posts_per_page'    => $per_page
                                        );
                                     $products  =   new WP_Query($args); 
                                      ?>
                                    <?php
                                    while($products->have_posts()): $products->the_post();      
                                                $id = get_the_ID();
                        $title      =   get_the_title(); 
                        $permalink  =   get_permalink(); 
                        $price      =   get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'wpc_product_price',true); 
                                                $product_id = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'product_ID', true);
                                                if(in_array($id, $_SESSION['cart'])){           
                                         echo '<li class="wpc-product-item">';
                                          echo '<a href="index.php?action=delete&id=' .$id. '">Verwijder </a>';
                                            echo '<input alt="hoeveelheid" maxlengt="2" value="' .$_GET["amount$id"]. '" min="1" type="number" max="99" name="amount'.$id.'" size="3" required> </input>';
                                         echo '<a href="'. $permalink .'"><div class="item-title"> ' .$title. ' </div></a>';
                                         echo '<a href="'. $permalink .'"><div class="item-take"> <img width="25px" src="http://bgc-testomgeving.nl/sem/wp-content/themes/sem/images/pijltje.png" /> </div></a>';
                                         echo '<a href="'. $permalink .'"><div class="item-nr"> &nbsp; '.$product_id. '</div></a>';
                                         if((isset($_GET["amount$id"]) && $_GET["amount$id"] == 1) || $_GET["amount$id"] == "" ){
                                                            if (is_numeric($price) && (floor($price) == $price)) {
                                                                echo '<div class="item-price"> &#8364;' .number_format ($price , 0 , "," , "." ). ',- </div>';
                                                            } 
                                                            else {                                                      
                                                                echo '<div class="item-price"> &#8364;' .$price. '</div>';
                                                            }
                                                            echo '</li>';
                                                }
                                        else if(isset($_GET["amount$id"]) && floatval($_GET["amount$id"]) > 1){
                                            changeFormat($price);
                                            $priceTotal =  number_format($price * floatval($_GET["amount$id"]), 2);
                                                if (is_numeric($priceTotal) && (floor($priceTotal) == $priceTotal)) {
                                                                echo '<div class="item-price"> &#8364;' .$priceTotal . ',- </div>';
                                                            }
                                                            else {
                                                                echo '<div class="item-price"> &#8364;' .$priceTotal . '</div>';
                                                            }
                                                            echo '</li>';
                                                }}      
                                     endwhile;
                                    ?>
                            </ul>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Bereken"> </input>
                            </form>
                            <div class="totalprice">
                                    <?php 
                                    (float)$total = 0;
                                    while($products->have_posts()): $products->the_post(); {                          
                                                $id = get_the_ID();
                        $title      =   get_the_title(); 
                        $permalink  =   get_permalink(); 
                        $price      =   get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'wpc_product_price',true); 
                                                $product_id = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'product_ID', true);
                                                if(in_array($id, $_SESSION['cart'])){           
                                            if (is_numeric($price) && (floor($price) == $price)) {
                                                $price = number_format($price, 2);
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                $price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);
                                            }                                       
                                            $total += (floatval($price) * floatval($_GET["amount$id"]));                    
                                    }}      
                                            endwhile;                       
                                            (String)$total;
                                            number_format($total, 2);
                                            $totalDecimal = str_replace('.', ',', $total);
                                            echo 'Subtotaal: &nbsp;&#8364;' .$totalDecimal. '<br />';
                                            echo 'BTW: &nbsp;&#8364;' . str_replace('.',',', number_format($total * 0.21,2)). '<br />';
                                            echo 'Totaal: &nbsp;&#8364;' . str_replace('.',',', number_format($total * 1.21,2));


                                            function changeFormat($var) {
                                                if(is_numeric($var) && (floor($var) == $var)){
                                                    return number_format($var, 0) + ',-';
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    if (is_numeric($var)) {
                                                        return number_format($var, 2, ',', '.');
                                                    }
                                                    else if (is_string ($var)){
                                                    return str_replace(',', '.', $var);
                                                }
                                                    else {
                                                        echo "What the hell is dit voor een formaat?";
                                                    }
                                            }}
                                    ?>

                            </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
    </main>
```

The calculate function and the orderlist are all working fine and i'm able to make a standard POST form as a contactform but I can't manage to get this done. I want the button 'send' to send the list plus the given amounts per product and the filled in contact forms.

The URL for this project is: http://www.bgc-testomgeving.nl/sem 
Underneath the http://www.bgc-testomgeving.nl/sem/offertelijst/ page should be the contact form but every time I try to build this I demolish my perfect order list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change your form method to post.

```
<form action="" method="post" value="offertelijst">
```

Then you have to create inputs for each item in your form element. I see this you have only Amount input in your form:

```
echo '<input alt="hoeveelheid" maxlengt="2" value="' .$_GET["amount$id"]. '" min="1" type="number" max="99" name="amount'.$id.'" size="3" required> </input>';
```

Create input for each element, since user doesnt need to see those inputs you can create them as hidden element, here is one example for item title:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="title['.$id.']" value="' .$title. '"</input>';
```

Put this below this line

```
echo '<a href="'. $permalink .'"><div class="item-title"> ' .$title. ' </div></a>';
```

After you created all inputs, also create second button near of this one:

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Bereken">
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Send">
```

So When the user click Bereken, you will do your calculation things, but if it is Send button, you will mail it to your self. here is Example code:

```
<?php
// if send button clicked
if($_POST["action"]=="Send")
{
    /// mail to your self all element
    mail("you@www.com","New Order",implode("-",$_POST));
}
?>
<main>
    <div class="main-center">
        <div class="offerte-container">
            <form action="" method="post" value="offertelijst">
                <ul class="offerte-list">
                    <?php
                    $per_page = 9;
                    $args = array(
                        'post_type'=> 'wpcproduct',
                        'order'     => 'ASC',
                        'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
                        'posts_per_page'    => $per_page
                    );
                    $products  =   new WP_Query($args);
                    ?>
                    <?php
                    while($products->have_posts()): $products->the_post();
                        $id = get_the_ID();
                        $title      =   get_the_title();
                        $permalink  =   get_permalink();
                        $price      =   get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'wpc_product_price',true);
                        $product_id = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'product_ID', true);
                        if(in_array($id, $_SESSION['cart'])){
                            echo '<li class="wpc-product-item">';
                            echo '<a href="index.php?action=delete&id=' .$id. '">Verwijder </a>';
                            echo '<input alt="hoeveelheid" maxlengt="2" value="' .$_GET["amount$id"]. '" min="1" type="number" max="99" name="amount'.$id.'" size="3" required> </input>';
                            echo '<a href="'. $permalink .'"><div class="item-title"> ' .$title. ' </div></a>';
                            // i added below input for example
                            echo '<input type="hidden" name="title['.$id.']" value="' .$title. '"</input>';
                            echo '<a href="'. $permalink .'"><div class="item-take"> <img width="25px" src="http://bgc-testomgeving.nl/sem/wp-content/themes/sem/images/pijltje.png" /> </div></a>';
                            echo '<a href="'. $permalink .'"><div class="item-nr"> &nbsp; '.$product_id. '</div></a>';
                            if((isset($_GET["amount$id"]) && $_GET["amount$id"] == 1) || $_GET["amount$id"] == "" ){
                                if (is_numeric($price) && (floor($price) == $price)) {
                                    echo '<div class="item-price"> &#8364;' .number_format ($price , 0 , "," , "." ). ',- </div>';
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo '<div class="item-price"> &#8364;' .$price. '</div>';
                                }
                                echo '</li>';
                            }
                            else if(isset($_GET["amount$id"]) && floatval($_GET["amount$id"]) > 1){
                                changeFormat($price);
                                $priceTotal =  number_format($price * floatval($_GET["amount$id"]), 2);
                                if (is_numeric($priceTotal) && (floor($priceTotal) == $priceTotal)) {
                                    echo '<div class="item-price"> &#8364;' .$priceTotal . ',- </div>';
                                }
                                else {
                                    echo '<div class="item-price"> &#8364;' .$priceTotal . '</div>';
                                }
                                echo '</li>';
                            }}
                    endwhile;
                    ?>
                </ul>
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Bereken">
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Send">
            </form>
            <div class="totalprice">
                <?php
                // is bereken button clickied
                if($_POST["action"]=="Bereken") {
                (float)$total = 0;
                while($products->have_posts()): $products->the_post(); {
                    $id = get_the_ID();
                    $title      =   get_the_title();
                    $permalink  =   get_permalink();
                    $price      =   get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'wpc_product_price',true);
                    $product_id = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'product_ID', true);
                    if(in_array($id, $_SESSION['cart'])){
                        if (is_numeric($price) && (floor($price) == $price)) {
                            $price = number_format($price, 2);
                        }
                        else {
                            $price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);
                        }
                        $total += (floatval($price) * floatval($_GET["amount$id"]));
                    }}
                endwhile;
                (String)$total;
                number_format($total, 2);
                $totalDecimal = str_replace('.', ',', $total);
                echo 'Subtotaal: &nbsp;&#8364;' .$totalDecimal. '<br />';
                echo 'BTW: &nbsp;&#8364;' . str_replace('.',',', number_format($total * 0.21,2)). '<br />';
                echo 'Totaal: &nbsp;&#8364;' . str_replace('.',',', number_format($total * 1.21,2));
                }

                function changeFormat($var) {
                    if(is_numeric($var) && (floor($var) == $var)){
                        return number_format($var, 0) + ',-';
                    }
                    else {
                        if (is_numeric($var)) {
                            return number_format($var, 2, ',', '.');
                        }
                        else if (is_string ($var)){
                            return str_replace(',', '.', $var);
                        }
                        else {
                            echo "What the hell is dit voor een formaat?";
                        }
                    }}
                ?>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</main>
```